# How do I mirror a collection?

Tags: mirror, collections

I have a collection of objects that comprise a room. I would like to 'mirror' it on an X or Y axis. While I can accomplish this with an individual object, I cannot figure out how to do it with a collection.

Update: Still haven't figured it out, but I am just going to align my objects individually until I can figure this out.

Comment: You could join all the objects together and then mirror one giant object then separate them in edit mode with P. Or alternatively set all of their origins to be in one spot then add individual mirror modifiers.

Comment: You can't simply add a modifier to a collection (would be a nice feature though) This is a great way to achieve the result though. It's old but still works: https://b3d.interplanety.org/en/how-to-copy-a-single-modifier-to-multiple-objects/

Comment: Thanks all. See, I was hoping to mirror the whole collection and not the constituent parts. Honestly, I would love to just *instance* the thing and then mirror THAT but am not sure that is a route I can take.

Comment: Why is a mirrored instance not an option?

Comment: You can mirror an instanced collection. Scale along the Axis by -1

Answer (score 8):

You can select all objects in your collection and add a *Mirror modifier* to one of them:

[image]

Now use *Make Links* → *Modifiers* to add the Mirror modifier to all of them:

[image]

Afterwards you can use *Convert to mesh* to apply the modifier to all the objects.

***there is an alternative solution:***

1. select collection
2. right click to "instance collection"
3. scale the instanced collection -1.0 in the desired axis.

Comment: I think this answer needs clarification:
1) Select collection in the Outliner
2) Right click on it > Instance To Scene
3) scale the instanced collection -1.0 in the desired axis
4) - optionally - Object > Apply > Make Instances Real, if you want to "explode / ungroup" the instanced collection to make it editable; otherwise it'll only be "virtual" or non-editable

Comment: Also, at the moment of creating your collection instance, 3D cursor must sit in the world origin. Only then the instance will be placed in the exact same place as the original collection, and then you can proceed to mirroring, e.g. by moving 3D cursor to a desired position and setting it as transform pivot point, if you want to mirror by 3D cursor.